# Google Maps AJAX call for Multiple Markers

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am using a jQuery $.post to hit a PHP page that returns my markers in the following format:

[['LOCATION1', LAT, LONG, 1],['LOCATION2', LAT, LONG, 2]]

I think the problem is that the javascript is treating this as a string instead of an array.  Here is my jQuery.

```
$.post("getdata.php")
    .done(function(locations) {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(LAT, LONG),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }   
    });
```

I tried to manually set the locations variable to my PHP result and it works so thats why I think it is something simple with how the AJAX variable is coming in and then how it is trying to parse it. Thanks in Advance.

EDIT: I ended up changing the format that the points came in to something like Location;Lat;Long|Location2;Lat;Long|

And then I split on the '|' and then split on the ';' to create 2 arrays to parse through.  Pretty ugly solution but it ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting the response with console.log(), or directly doing a jQuery.parseJSON before iterating through it.

```
$.post("getdata.php")
    .done(function(_locations) {
        locations = jQuery.parseJSON(_locations);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(LAT, LONG),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }   
    });
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: console.log(locations) on my code displays the results that I want, but then when I try to do locations[i][1] in my for loop it gets a undefined.  I still think it is treating locations as a string instead of an array. Is there a way to convert the format to an array?

Comment: can you post the output of console.log(locations) or _locations?
Yes, it could be related to it

Comment: I do not want to post the actual output for privacy concerns, but the format is as posted above [['LOCATION1', LAT, LONG, 1],['LOCATION2', LAT, LONG, 2]] but with about 50 locations.